# In node can we use multiple mysql statements in one connection query?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, node-mysql

In node-socketchat system, i am using mysql module.

I wants to take data after checking through 4-5 tables, but cannot make a join statement.

suppose i need to take a friends collection and their details.

Now i am following below method.

```
var friends = new Array();
var connection = mysql.createConnection(database);
connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {

 if (err) throw err;
 for (var key in rows) {

  friends.push(rows[key].friendid);
  // Here i am expecting to write another sql statement     
 }
 getfriendsdetails(friends)
 connection.end();

})

function getfriendsdetails(friendslist){
  connection = mysql.createConnection(database);
  sql = 'select statment for taking friends details in in statement'
  connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
  //storing each row detail in to an array
  });
 }
```

My Question is, can i call the details query inside first for loop ? is it possible ?

Comment: Dealing with callback here will be painful. You should look for "promises"

Comment: @dystroy ... thanks for the suggestion.. i will go through it.